# Regular expression to match: Specific sign + anything + Specific sgin

Tags: regex

I need help with regular expression that will count brackets which are opend and closed.

Example:

`"hello ( asdas ) hello ("` should return 1.

`" ( . / . \n sssss ) ( hey ( hello )"` should return 2.

So the pattern looks like : ( + anthing + ).

Thank you!

*Edit*

I tried something like `\(.*\)`. It isn't good cuz `.` is not taking new lines.

Comment: Regexps do not count, use language-specific means for that. With a regex, you can *match* (find a piece of text following a certain pattern) only.

Comment: I'm using matcher for counting occurences of pattern.

Comment: So, what pattern have you tried?

Comment: \\(.*\\) , something like this. I know it won't be good for sure cuz "." is not taking new lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\(.*\)` pattern takes anything between the first `(` up to the last `)` on the line (if DOTALL modifier is not set), or up to the last `)` in the whole string (if DOTALL modifier is set). You need to restrict this pattern.

To match a substring from the `(` till the next `)`, you can use a *negated character class based regex*:

```
\([^)]*\)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nN0iI1/1)

**Explanation:**

- `\(` - literal `(`
- `[^)]*` - zero or more characters other than `)`
- `\)` - closing `)`

A negated character class will also match newline symbols (if any).

Comment: Thank you, everthing works fine, I didn't even think about negation.